# Should name lookup be deferred for a class/namespace-name qualified by this-> in a class template definition?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

clang 3.0 and g++ 4.8.1 both reject the following code with the error shown in the comment:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    void f()
    {
        this->dependent(); // no error: type of 'this' is dependent?
        this->Dependent::dependent(); // error: 'Dependent' has not been declared
    }
};
```

According to [basic.lookup.classref]

> the class-name-or-namespace-name following the . or -> operator is looked up both in the context of the entire postfix-expression and in the scope of the class of the object expression.

And [temp.dep.expr]

> `this` is type-dependent if the class type of the enclosing member function is dependent.

If the class-or-namespace-name `Dependent` is looked up 'in the scope of the class of the object expression* `this`, and the class of the object expression is dependent, should this lookup not be deferred until the template is instantiated? Does the standard specify the correct behaviour?

EDIT: clang 3.0 accepts the following code, but g++4.8 gives the same error as above

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    T m;
    void f()
    {
        m.dependent();
        m.Dependent::dependent();
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see how `this->Dependent::dependent()` could be a dependent expression. How does it depend on the template parameter?

Comment: [temp.dep.expr] "`this` is type-dependent if the class type of the enclosing member function is dependent".

Comment: The second code make sens as it could depend on the template but not the first.
For me, both the first and the second code compile fine on clang3, g++4.8.1 and msvc_110 unless of course I try to instantiate the first code

Comment: clang 3.0 or 3.2? clang 3.0 definitely rejects the first code fragment.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/17579889#17579889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code, *both* lines are "illformed, no diagnostic required" because "this" refers to the current instantiation, but no member was found and the class template has no dependent base classes.

It is neither a member of the current instantiation, nor of an unknown specialization. See 14.6.2.1p6

Comment: Which version of the standard are you quoting? I guess this language was added since C++03.

Comment: @willj even in C++03 it was "illformed, NDR" however there was no specific rule for it, just the general "if no valid specialization can be generated, the template is ill-formed; NDR". Now we have specific rules.

Comment: So a class counts as a 'compound type' composed of its 'sequence of members and base class objects', in which case `this` is dependent if its type has a dependent base-class?

Comment: @willj "this" is always dependent in a template. But that does not mean that `this->foo` necessarily is dependent.